# The system cannot find the file specified in cmder

Tags: windows, terminal, environment-variables, system, cmder

[image: "The system cannot find the file specified" warning on cmder terminal]

Even though all works well, still this warning is always being shown whenever i open Cmder.
Been searching for solution, for nearly 2 days..ughh

Thanks in advance..

Comment: If you need help then asking for it should come in the form of a question not a statement. That said it looks like either you are missing a system file that cmder needs somewhere in the cmder directory or you have something in your cusomization files such as `profile.d` or `init.bat` that is failing. Get debug information:  settings-->info-->debug  check 'Exec', keep settings open, launch a new cmder session, you will see the cmder startup process in the output, click `save as` and open that file and paste it's contents into your question so we can help you debug the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I manually created the folder "**C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\usr**". This folder is expected but did not exist on my system.

I found the workaround here: https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/121#issuecomment-654171568

Comment: I had to create the additional "bin" folder within that new "usr" folder so path was "..\Git\mingw64\bin\usr\bin". With only the "usr" folder in place I got a "File Not Found" error instead.